# First Program not going well

Tags: python

Running python 3.7.9

entered this code straight from a book

```
 # This program says hello and asks for my name
print('Hello, world!')
print('What is your name?')    # ask for their name
myName = input(Matt)
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('What is your age?')    # ask for their age
myAge = input(22)
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

Receiving error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/matth/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/hello.py", line 4, in 
myName = input(Matt)
NameError: name 'Matt' is not defined

Comment: Does the book literally say `input(Matt)`? if so you need a new book

Comment: You need to enter `Matt` when you run the program. `myName = input('What is your name?')`

Comment: @Ethan technically correct, but doesn't make sense in the context of this code

Comment: It might be worth a read through the [python documentation for the input() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: Note that you have a _similar_ issue with `myAge = input(22)` However this will run because `22` is a literal value. Most likely you want: `myAge = input('What is your age?')`

Comment: Yeah I figured it out thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input function receives string as argument. String needs to passed on double quotes. If you're not using double quotes, it will be treated as variable. So use

```
myName = input()
```

or

```
myName = input("Enter your name")
```

While running system will ask for the input at that time you can enter your name

Answer (score 0):

Hoping now you understand input()....
The is something important you should know...

```
myAge = input(22)
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

that was in your code

actually the type `myAge` is already string so you should not say  `str(int(myAge))`
because it is the same as saying .... `str(int(str))`

*The type of any input is str